# My MacBook Pro (2019) background keeps going black every 4-7 seconds

Tags: macos, catalina, big-sur, memory, monterey

My MacBook pro background keeps going black every 4-7 seconds. When it goes black, the dock at the bottom slides out and then slides back up when the screen goes to the regular background. Something to keep in mind is that only the background goes black. Any application or software I have open stays fine.

Something else I have noticed is that I got a process named ifilogin-helper that starts at about 200mb of ram and continuously grows. The highest it has gone without a restart has been 16GB. I'm not super knowledgeable on macOS but that doesn't seem right.

When did all of this start happening? I think this might be all related to a background image change I did (However I've changed that all around to every possible thing and it still does it) or it might be because it downloaded macOS Monterey? But this wouldn't make any sense because I cannot upgrade my machine anyways (this is my works computer and Monterey is blocked).

After the screen goes black, if I had something minimized, it will bring it back up. Note that none of this happens on the login screen at all and does happen on the computers screen as well as any external monitors.

I've tried anything I can find on the web and have had no luck. It does the same thing on safe mode, I cleared the ram, smc, turned off true tone, changed to many backgrounds, nothing. Does anybody have any idea what this could be?

EDIT: I noticed in the following in the console logs:

`batteryImage = <CGImage 0x7fa74ac3e8e0> (DP) <<CGColorSpace 0x7fa74c00d020> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)> width = 28, height = 14, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 128  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGImageByteOrder32Little  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked  is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes`

There are a ton of those in the logs. So I unplugged the power and noticed that the icon still show it as plugged in and 100%. I restarted my mac with the cable unplugged and in the login screen it shows the actual percentage and the icon displays as unplugged.

Edit #2: Adding Diagnostics report:

`/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/mds_2021-12-02-144811.wakeups_resource.diag`

- `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/mds_2021-12-02-164842.crash`
- `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SecurityAgent_2021-12-02-164844.crash`
- /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SecurityAgent_2021-12-02-172939.crash`
- `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SecurityAgent_2021-12-02-173350.crash`
- `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-145426.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-150526.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-151617.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-163430.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-164257.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-164845.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-172323.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-172627.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-172942.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-173215.shutdownStall`
- `shutdown_stall_2021-12-02-182525.shutdownStall`
- `studio_2021-12-02-153415.cpu_resource.diag`
- `studio_2021-12-02-153417.wakeups_resource.diag`

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add a code block containing the names of all files in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`?

Comment: You have three versions of macOS tagged. Your question implies that Monterey was downloaded but not installed because your laptop is under management by your employer. If the process **e**filogin-helper not _ifilogin-helper_ then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958896/efilogin-helper-running-continuously-at-high-cpu-on-macbook-pro/51688899) at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @IconDaemon I had macos catalina, downloaded Monterey but couldn't update and finally installed Big Sur today but the issue persisted. I updated the question with some more info I found

Comment: @pion I added the files above

Comment: about half-hour after being unplugged, the icon finally updated to unplugged. Then I just plugged it in and it still shows the same unplugged icon. Safe to say something is going on with it

Comment: Can you boot into Recovery and run Disk First Aid? And can you run Apple Diagnostics?

Comment: Icon? Plugged? Unplugged? Don't see any mention of this in earlier comments or the body of your question. I suggest you speak with your IT department, especially the technicians who manage the MDM (I'm guessing) for your company's laptops. There may be a configuration messed up in a profile or something.

Comment: @IconDaemon Yeah, I've been doing that. Might just get another laptop anyways. Just wanted to ask this somewhere in case this was some easy fix or something someone has seen before